# PHP Laravel - Class [controllername] Controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to develop a custom Laravel Package, but is having some issues with getting started.

This is my file structure:

```
-packages
  - oliverbusk
   -invoiceconverter
    -src
      -controllers 
         - InvoiceconverterController.php
      -resources
         - views
           - home.blade.php
      -routes
         - web.php
    - InvoiceConverterServiceProvider.php
```

So as you can see, I have my files inside the `src/` folder.

First of all, this is my `composer.json`, **inside my package folder**:

```
"extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Oliverbusk\\Invoiceconverter\\InvoiceConverterServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have then autoloaded this in my projects **main** `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
  //....
  "oliverbusk/invoiceconverter": "dev-feature-package"
},
"autoload": {
        [...]
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Oliverbusk\\Invoiceconverter\\": "packages/oliverbusk/invoiceconverter"
        }
},
```

This is my serviceprovider file:

```
namespace Oliverbusk\Invoiceconverter;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class InvoiceConverterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Load our routes
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__ . '/routes/web.php');

        //Load our views
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/resources/views', 'invoiceconverter');
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
      //
    }
}
```

And my controller file, located in `controllers/`:

```
namespace Oliverbusk\Invoiceconverter\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class InvoiceconverterController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('invoiceconverter::home');
    }
}
```

Last, my `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Oliverbusk\InvoiceConverter\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('invoiceconverter', 'InvoiceconverterController@index');
});
```

## Error :

> Class Oliverbusk\InvoiceConverter\Controllers\InvoiceconverterController does not exist

## Bonus info:

**Composer dump autoload** shows the following:

```
Discovered Package: oliverbusk/invoiceconverter
```

- I have already tried to clear the cache with `php artisan:cache:clear`.
- I have also tried `composer update`

Comment: try to publish the code `php artisan vendor:publish`

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference but you should make sure your `controllers` directory is capitalised to match the namespace, so it should be `Controllers`. That could well be it though. Same goes for your class name and the file it is in, try to keep the same casing.

Comment: @urfusion - This package does not yet publish anything.

Comment: @Jonathon - just tried changing the folder name to `Controllers` - did not work.

Comment: Did you try changing the class name to match the name of the file, or the name of the file to match the class name?

Comment: @Jonathon yes - no changes unfortunately..

Comment: Do you have InvoiceConverterController or InvoiceconverterController you have used both in your example

Comment: @JamesCook - good catch. Only `InvoiceconverterController.php` - updated

Comment: The namespace in your route group is also not capitalised the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace in your route does not match the namespacing your have actually used.

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Oliverbusk\InvoiceConverter\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('invoiceconverter', 'InvoiceconverterController@index');
});
```

Change to

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Oliverbusk\Invoiceconverter\Controllers'], function () 
{
    Route::get('invoiceconverter', 'InvoiceconverterController@index');
});
```

And see if that helps.

I would also recommend you refactor all your code to be capitalised InvoiceConverter as they are two separate words.